# How can extract part of a string separated by spaces?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

If I have string like:

```
String^ str ="hhB2LWq50a+9HZiNLKuwdQ==.pdf aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb cccccdddddeee ffffffgggghhh";
```

and I want to extract the first part of it which is

`hhB2LWq50a+9HZiNLKuwdQ==.pdf`

How can do that in C++/CLI or C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.IndexOf` to find the first space, then `string.Substring` to copy:

```
string str ="hhB2LWq50a+9HZiNLKuwdQ==.pdf aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb cccccdddddeee";
int spacePos = str.IndexOf(' ');
if (spacePos == -1)
    return null;
else
    return str.Substring(0, spacePos);
```

This assumes that the string doesn't have any leading spaces. If it can have leading spaces, you should probably call `Trim` on it first.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a.aspx) method

```
string str ="hhB2LWq50a+9HZiNLKuwdQ==.pdf aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb cccccdddddeee";
string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
if (parts != null)
{
   string firstPart = parts[0];
}
```

Or using LINQ [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;

string firstPart = str.Split(' ').First();
```

Answer (score 1):

in C# it's so easy

```
string tem = "test test";
string[] s = tem.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(s[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression to parse your string and extract the desire text